# Visual Studio C++ Unable to find a header file from another directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I know this question has been asked else where, but none of the posts I have tried seem to offer any fixes for my problem.

I have a fresh project in Visual Studio 2017 to build a DLL file that will be using some C++ code from another project (that project is done in Eclipse, however for what I'm doing, it's more convenient to have this project in Visual Studio).

So, I've created the fresh project, and then I tried adding the files I need directly.  When I include them with "Add Existing", the file gets added into the project, inspecting the new file shows that the file lives out at the location I added it from, as expected.  Attempting #include this file into my main, just to simply test it out, the #include is underlined indicating an error which says, "cannot open source file "thefile.h"".

"thefile.h" (not the actual name) has no other dependencies, and simply contains an enum.  I've seen two separate places suggested to use to add includes, both are contained into the project properties (alt-enter the project name).  Under VC++ Directories, in the "Include Directories" field, I added the location of the file I am attempting to include.  The other location is under C/C++ / General in the Additional Include Directories, where I added the location once again.  In the directory where this file comes from, there is an "inc" and a "src" folder, it is unclear whether I am supposed to use the parent directory of "inc" or use "inc" itself, but I have tried both with no success.

Maybe I just don't know how to ask Google the right questions for exactly my problem, but I am going nuts with this.  I've tried reloading the project, I've tried closing Visual Studio and reopening the solution, both without success.  I figure I must be missing something, but I just can't figure it out and figured I'd ask online to see if anyone has an wisdom to what I could be doing wrong.

EDIT:

Here are some photos of my process:

1) The photo below shows my basic main function, compiles without the `#include "test.h"` or the `int result = Test();` lines.

[image]

2) The relative path to `test.h` shown.

[image]

3) The relative path to `test.cpp` shown.
[image]

4) My VC++ Directories > Include Directories shown.

[image]

5) My C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories shown.

[image]

These are all the steps I took to create my example project.  Am I missing a step here?  Are my directories wrong?  My folder containing the .h and .cpp file I'm trying to use are located at C:\ExampleExternalSource.  My project is located out of the default Visual Studio 2017 Projects folder, C:\Users\MyUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Example.

Comment: ***Under VC++ Directories, in the "Include Directories" field, I added the location of the file I am attempting to include. The other location is under C/C++ / General in the Additional Include Directories,*** That is what you are supposed to do. Prefer the per project includes if you don't plan on including this library in most of your projects in the future.

Comment: Remember that the project settings are per configuration unless you selected multiple configurations.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment is supposed to help.  This is a fresh project, I've included the files I want to use, that didn't work, so I tried including the directory where it lives, and it still doesn't work.  From your comment, I'm not seeing how this is supposed to fix the issue.  I figure it has to be something I'm doing wrong, either that or I start pointing fingers at VS2017 and playing the blame game.

Comment: My advice is open the file explorer and paste the exact folder you added to your include directories to make sure it is correct.

Comment: Another trick is to install procmon from Microsoft and watch the filepaths that VS is trying to hit while searching for your .h file.  Set up the filter so that it only includes paths that include your thefile.h filename.  That's usually enough for me to discover how I've messed up my build settings.

Comment: ***I tried including the directory where it lives, and it still doesn't work*** I expect you entered the wrong folder. That is why I want you to test it in explorer. Perhaps you have spaces in your path and you did not quote the path.

Comment: @drescherjm I just removed all my paths, removed the file I am trying to include, opened a explorer window, found my file, opened it to make sure it was what I want, dragged and dropped it in "Header Files" section of my project.  Same exact issue.  I readded the paths, same exact issue.

Comment: @Zulukas Including a file in the "header files" section of Solution Explorer doesn't mean that the `#include ` statement will succeed

Comment: ***dragged and dropped it in "Header Files"*** You don't want to do that. You need to add the folder containing the file in your projects `c++` settings in the "Additional Include Directories" setting.

Comment: It may take a bit of work to interpret the results, but try right clicking on the file that's causing trouble in Solution Explorer, and selecting Properties.  Open up the C/C++ section, and the very last entry is "Command Line".  Select your Configuration and Platform, and it'll show the exact command line handed to CL.EXE.  In particular, you care about the `/I` options.

Comment: You're probably change the settings for one build configuration and build another one. If you're compiling Debug 64, opening project properties does not take you automatically to Debug 64 Properties - you must check that in the upper part of properties page.

Comment: @drescherjm Could you write up an answer for what you're suggesting I do, or if you know of a post that outlines what you're trying to explain could you link it?  I'm having a difficult time following what you're trying to instruct me to do.

Comment: I did not write an answer because I have yet to figure out how you have done this wrongly. We need some more info. Perhaps a minimal example and pictures of your settings.

Comment: What settings do you need to see?

Comment: A small program that has your #include statements. Your error messages. The folder that contains your headers. And exactly what was typed in the "Additional Include Directories" setting.

Comment: Okay, I added some photos.  If you need to see anything else let me know.

Comment: I would remove `test.h` from your project. The "Additional Include Directories" should be enough. Make sure you enabled this setting for every configuration (Release, Debug ...) the settings are independent.

Comment: I think someone else may have to help with a suggestion. I have done this 1000s of times but not sure how this is failing for you.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear this issue is something on my work PC.  I ran the same test on my personal PC at home and following drescherjm's final suggestions about removing the .h file from the project allowed me to build the project.

One final update that **got it working**

Enter project properties, make sure that the configuration and platform are what you need.  I set mine to "All Configurations" and "All Platforms". Adding the path to my include directory allowed the path to be discovered and the header included.